# Error in my angular app structure

Tags: angularjs

My angular app structure is like this

```
  Controllers.js

     angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).
            controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) {

            });

        angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

        });

        angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

        });

    App.JS

        angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
       'RateRequestApp.services',
       'RateRequestApp.controllers',
       'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);
```

HTML

```
<div id="RateRequestApp" class="content" ng-app='RateRequestApp' ng-controller="ReadOnlyController">
    <form name="palletForm" novalidate>

        <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            </script>


        </div>


    </form>
</div>
```

everything looks okay to me, but this throws an error

```
  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ReadOnlyController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out.

Comment: @deitch added anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the new module 'RateRequestApp.controllers' multiple times.

Each time you do:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers',[])
```

You are **redefining** the module 'RateRequestApp.controllers', because you are declaring the dependencies (although empty) in the second argument. When you did:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).
        controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) {

        });
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    });
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    });
```

The second definition threw out the first, and the third threw out the second. See here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module scroll down to "Usage" and look at the Details of the "requires" arg: "If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration."

Either do this (notice only the first `.module()` has the requirements):

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).
        controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) {

        });
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    });
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    });
```

Or more simply:

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).
        controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) {

        }).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    }).controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    });
```

Comment: your solution works good for me. Can you please explain the difference between your two solutions little more clear. and which approach you suggests

Comment: They are equally good. The second is just chaining them. When you call `angular.module('mod').controller()` it returns the angular module, allowing you to chain it. So `angular.module('mod').controller().controller()` is identical to `angular.module('mod').controller(); angular.module('mod').controller();`

Answer (score 1):

You create a module once using: `angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', [])`

Then later define different controllers on that module by getting the module like

```js
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers')
  .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {});
```

Passing `[]` to module definition creates a new module.